# Selenium Automation on AirAsia

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Unable to select the destination after logging into the airasia.com.
Below is the code I have used for clicking on destination. Please let me know if the way to select the destination using the search button of location.

```
WebDriver d=new ChromeDriver();   
d.get("https://www.airasia.com/en/home.page?cid=1");
  System.out.println(d.getCurrentUrl());

Assert.assertEquals(d.getCurrentUrl(),"https://www.airasia.com/en/home.page?cid=1");
  System.out.println(d.getTitle());
  Assert.assertEquals(d.getTitle(),"AirAsia | Book cheap flights online to over 120 destinations!");
  d.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Log in")).click();
  d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'username-input--login\']")).sendKeys("username");
  d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'password-input--login\']")).sendKeys("password");
  d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"loginbutton\"]")).click();
   WebElement isPresent=d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'select2-cb_origins-container\']/span/div/span[1]"));
  isPresent.sendKeys("Auckland");
  System.out.println(isPresent);
```

Comment: can you share the set of demo credentials to login into the website?

Comment: Do you mean Origin instead of Destination? Clicking on the destination without first selecting an origin will give no results.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following selectors:

Xpath: //span[@id='select2-cb_destinations-container']//span[@class='destination-city']

Css: .destination-city

Answer (score 0):

d.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/span/span/span[1]/input")).sendKeys("Jaipur");
Robot r= new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

This one worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for enter destination and select exact destination.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class = 'select2-search__field']")).sendKeys("Your Destination");
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text() = 'Your Destination']")).click();
```